# android OS not accepting the landscape mode design on orintation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

My application having landscape and portrait mode. so I designed two layouts for each mode. In manifest file I set the below code.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

it's working fine but the activity restarts on every orientation changes. so I add the following line to avoid the recreate issue.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Now the activity is not recreating but it also not taking the landscape mode design.

please help me to solve this issue friends

Comment: The activity recreation is intended to redraw with the proper layout, if you disable it, it will now draw your landscape layout.

Comment: You should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8093902/3743245 is older than Jesus

Comment: That's how orientation works: by recreating the Activity. If you disable it... you lose it. It appears quite obvious. Or isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend letting the Application recreate itself on orientation change.

If you need to preserve state then store information when onSaveInstanceState is called.

```
/**
 * On min or rotate save state info.
 *
 * @param bundle saved values
 */
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {

    bundle.putBoolean("SomeKey", someKeyValue);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

and then recover the values in onCreate

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("SomeKey")) {
            someKeyValue=  
               savedInstanceState.getBoolean("SomeKey");
        }

    }
```

Using onConfigChanges: is a slippery slope that works well until it doesn't.
Behavior varies and gets more complex with each OS release.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my app work fine in both orientation here is what i doing may it help you,

> use same code in **public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // your code }** and **public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { // your code }**

and in AndroidManifest file

use like

```
 <activity
        android:name="YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

that's it. if any issue post your comment